# I blocked someone from contacting me on iPhone. I then sent an angry message to them that I regret. Did they see the message?

Tags: iphone, messages, contacts

I know this sounds petty. It is. Regardless, I must know the answer. I was angry with the person I have an intimate relationship. I blocked him on my iPhone, in his contact profile, so that he could not contact me. I then sent him a message while I was still upset, a message I truly regret. Did he receive the message?? I still have him blocked because I don't think either of us are ready to talk.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What app did you use to send the message? (_Apple Messages,_ _WhatsApp,_ …)

Comment: the standard iMessages that comes with iPhone. nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Blocking someone and being able to send them messages [are two different things](https://discussions.apple.com/message/30401966#30401966):

> Yes, you have only blocked seeing that they called or texted you. Blocking has nothing to do with outgoing calls or texts.

Your iMessage has most likely been delivered to, and displayed on, one or more of the recipient’s iOS and macOS devices.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I feel terrible... Good to have the answer though...